# Fill a WCHAR array with filepaths

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to fill a `WCHAR` array with several file paths to textures in C++ but I cant seem to understand how to do it.

How I'm doing it now :

```
WCHAR WallTextureArray[]={L"../Engine/data/wall01.dds",L"../Engine/data/wall02.dds"};
```

And this is not compiling at all. If I do it with just one filepath it fills every index of the array with a single character and I need `WallTextureArray[0]` to contain a full filepath and so on.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try an array of pointers: `WCHAR * WallTextureArray[] = {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this definition:

> ```
> WCHAR WallTextureArray[] = { ...
> ```

you defined an array of `WCHAR`'s, i.e. a *string*.

If you want an *array of strings*, then you can define an array of *pointers to `WCHAR`s*:

```
const WCHAR* WallTextureArray[] = { 
    L"../Engine/data/wall01.dds",
    L"../Engine/data/wall02.dds"
};
```

(Since those are string literals and you can't modify them, I've added `const`.)

---

Note that in modern C++ you may want to use a convenient container class like **`std::vector`** instead of a raw C-style array, and use `std::wstring` for `WCHAR`-based strings, e.g.

```
#include <string>   // For std::wstring
#include <vector>   // For std::vector

....
std::vector<std::wstring> WallTextureArray = {
    L"../Engine/data/wall01.dds",
    L"../Engine/data/wall02.dds"
};
```

You can access the single strings in the array using the usual `[]` syntax (e.g. `WallTextureArray[0]` is the first string, `WallTextureArray[1]` is the second string, etc.).

Moreover, given a `std::wstring`, if you need a pointer to the raw C-style NUL-terminated string (e.g. for interop with C APIs), you can call the `std::wstring::c_str()` method.

You can also add more strings to the vector, e.g. using the `std::vector::push_back()` method:

```
WallTextureArray.push_back(L"../Engine/data/another_wall.dds");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code declares a 1-d array of wide characters, but you need one that is 2d (an array of arrays of wchars). The first dimension is the number of strings, the second is the maximum length of any string. So perhaps `WCHAR WallTextureArray[][50]` would give you what you want (at least until you have a filename that is longer than 49 characters).

If you don't want to fuss around with raw types and sizes, you could also use `std::vector<std::wstring>>`.

Edit: Johnny Mopp's comment will also work and is less fragile since it doesn't require you to fix the second dimension. I recommend this over my original suggestion.

Comment: What is "ETA" in this context?

Comment: @Lightness "Edited to add"

Comment: Thanks for the information. That said, the revision history already tracks changes so it seems redundant?

Comment: @Lightness Maybe. My thought was that it would take less work to figure it out this way, but I can quit doing it if people think it's just clutter.

Comment: _I_ think it's just clutter but I'm not aware of a consensus.